# Flutter StreamSubscription failing on 2nd call

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a StreamSubscription I call to place a `locationmarker` on a map within a Flutter app and then track location to update.

My app opens on the page and loads it fine the 1st time round.

When a user navigates to another page and then returns is where it fails & doesn't show marker.

I have tracked the error and it doesn't enter into the `StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream...` the 2nd time round

I understand that Streams can only be subscribed to once, however I couldn't get a `Broadcast` to work with `Position` inside. Should I cancel Stream on navigation off page or make it a broadcast perhaps?

Here is the method that is called when map initializes

```
  void _addLocationIndicator(GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates, LocationIndicatorIndicatorStyle indicatorStyle) {
    LocationIndicator locationIndicator = LocationIndicator();
    locationIndicator.locationIndicatorStyle = indicatorStyle;

    final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
    distanceFilter: 100,
    );

//DOES NOT GET PAST HERE 2ND TIME ROUND
    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
   
   (Position position) {
    GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (position.latitude, 
   position.longitude);
   
    bearing = position.heading;

    Location location = Location.withCoordinates(geoCoordinates);
    location.time = DateTime.now();
    location.bearingInDegrees = bearing;

    locationIndicator.updateLocation(location);

    _hereMapController.addLifecycleListener(locationIndicator);
    _locationIndicatorList.add(locationIndicator);
  });
  positionStream = positionStream;
  }
```

Any advice on how to make Stream work when user returns to page after leaving is appreciated.

Comment: You need to dispose the listener when the user first leaves the page

Comment: I thought this might be a solution. Would it be an @overide style? And where should I place it, in the page on main.dart or within the ```mapload``` method in another dart file? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how, since you first performed this assignment in a function, but try to assign the Stream in a widget body.

Comment: Actually your usage should be like this
The StreamSubscription element should be created only once and be listened to continuously or you should close the connection every time you leave the page this element is running on so you don't force an already connected connection when the page reloads.

Comment: Would making it a ```broadcast``` solve this too? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved by keeping Stream active on all pages, regardless of whether they display map or not. This way when user returns their location is still streaming